How to bold text between 1. and :
One of the functions of the library is to auto bold any text that appears between "." and ":"
For example:

Class A: This is class A. In class A, there are many other classes that we might discussed. For instance: Sub-categories of class A.

Class B: This is class B


A. Class C: This is class C.
B. Class D: This is class D.
i. Class E: This is class E.
ii. Class F: This is class F
What I want here is only text that appears between 1. and :, 2. and :, A. and :, B. and :, i. and :, ii. and : should be bold.
Note: I know this could be achieved via CSS if they were to be ul, ol items. But the script am writing should be able to bold any matches even if ul, ol are not used.
I have tried but mine will bold even matches found in middle of content which is not the purpose. Even if for instance, we "This is a . And here is a :", I don't want And here is a to be bold.
I don't know if the explanation is clear but I will try and give more details upon request.
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    // Get the text content of the div
    var text = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
    // Regex pattern to match the text between the number/letter and the colon
    var pattern = /(\d+\.|\w\.\s?)([^:]+)(?=\s*:)/g;
    // Replace matched text with bold tags around both the number/letter and the content after it
    var modifiedText = text.replace(pattern, function(match, p1a, p2a) {
      return "<b>" + p1a + "</b><b>" + p2a.trim() + "</b>";
    });
    //alert(modifiedText);
    // Update the content of the element with the modified text          document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = modifiedText;
  };
</script>

This image shows the preview of the script:

From the image you can see aside the listed items bold, some part of the write were also bold which is not supposed to be so.

Please post, as text, a complete input. From your image I guess there is a colon at the end of the first line and it is a match. You should improve your constraints: a letter, a colon and a whitespace are always present at the end of a sentence, for example

Are you really after a general markup converter?  There are many available.  What you're missing here is that you have to take line endings into account.  You only want to look for dots after numbers or roman numerals at the start of a line.

Why aren't you using something like <dl> for this?

You're almost there.
As it stands, your regex needed a few modfications (and may need a few more if your constraints become more elaborate).
This is the regex I used:
/(([\dA-Z]|[ivx]+)\.\s[^\.]+?\:)/g

In each paragraph, this regex will look for the following match one or more times:

([\dA-Z]|[ivx]+) - begins with a single digit or a single capital letter OR any number of i, v, x characters
. - followed by a period
\s - followed by a space
[^\.]+ - followed by any number of characters, none of which is a period
?\: - ending at the very first colon following the characters immediately above


Example:


const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
  paragraph.innerHTML = paragraph.innerHTML.replace(/(([\dA-Z]|[ivx]+)\.\s[^\.]+?\:)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');  
});
<p>1. Class A: This is class A. In class A, there are many other classes that we might discussed. For instance: Sub-categories of class A.</p>

<p>2. Class B: This is class B</p>

<p>A. Class C: This is class C. B. Class D: This is class D.</p>

<p>i. Class E: This is class E. ii. Class F: This is class F</p>



